# How to write a primereact Dialog component that has a Carousel inside to show an modal to view image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dialog, carousel, primereact

I'm wrtiting a React component (version 18.2) that whenever an image is clicked on, it show a modal (in this case, a dialog) for viewing that image, and carousel to handle next and previous image transition. I'm using primereact library (version 9.6.7). The Dialog and Carousel is a component (name MediaCarousel) that take a array of imageUrl as prop. The component that render array of images (name MediaTab) call to MediaCarousel), but the Dialog won't show and I can't figure out why.

Here MediaTab component:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import MediaCarousel from "../../../../layouts/commons/MediaCarousel/index.jsx";

function MediaTab() {
    const tabs = ["Photos", "Videos"]

    const [type, setType] = useState("Photos")
    const [images, setImages] = useState([
        {
            id: '1',
            imageUrl: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1595433707802-6b2626ef1c91?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8Mnx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&w=1000&q=80'
        },
        {
            id: '2',
            imageUrl: 'https://placehold.co/600x400'
        },
        {
            id: '3',
            imageUrl: 'https://placehold.co/400'
        }
    ])

    const [selectedImageIndex, setSelectedImageIndex] = useState(-1);
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/mediatab/1")
            .then(response => {
                setImages(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }, []);

    const handleClick = (index) => {
        setSelectedImageIndex(index);
        setShowModal(true);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="card w-100 d-block d-flex shadow-xss rounded-xxl border-0 mt-3">
                <div className="card-body d-flex p-4">
                    <h2 className="fw-700 mb-0 mt-0 font-md text-grey-900">Media</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="card-body d-block w-100 mb-0 p-0">
                    <ul className="nav nav-tabs h55 d-flex product-info-tab border-bottom-0 ps-4"
                        id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
                        {tabs.map((tab) => (
                            <li key={tab} className="list-inline-item me-5 ">
                                <span data-toggle="tab"
                                      onClick={() => setType(tab)}
                                      className={type === tab ?
                                          "fw-600 font-xsss text-dark pt-3 pb-3 ls-1 d-inline-block cursor-pointer border-bottom-dark" :
                                          "fw-600 font-xssss text-grey-500 pt-3 pb-3 ls-1 d-inline-block cursor-pointer"}>
                                    {tab}
                                </span>
                            </li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <div className="row ps-2 pe-2">
                        {images.map((image, index) => (
                            <div className="col-md-3 col-xss-6 pe-2 ps-2" key={image.id}>
                                <div
                                    className="card h240 w240 d-block border-0 rounded-3 mb-3 bg-image-cover"
                                    style={{backgroundImage: `url(${image.imageUrl}`}}
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        setSelectedImageIndex(index);
                                        setShowModal(true);
                                        console.log(selectedImageIndex, showModal);
                                    }}
                                >
                                    <a href="#" className="float-right mt-2 me-3"
                                       id="dropdownMenu4" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                                       aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                                        <i className="ti-more-alt text-grey-900 font-xss"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <div
                                        className="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-start p-4 rounded-xxl border-0 shadow-lg"
                                        aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu4">
                                        <div className="card-body p-0 d-flex mt-2">
                                            <i className="ti-reload text-grey-500 me-3 font-lg"></i>
                                            <h4 className="fw-600 text-grey-900 font-xssss mt-0 me-4">
                                                Change Location
                                                <span className="d-block font-xsssss fw-500 mt-1 lh-3 text-grey-500">Save to your saved items</span>
                                            </h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="card-body p-0 d-flex mt-2">
                                            <i className="ti-trash text-grey-500 me-3 font-lg"></i>
                                            <h4 className="fw-600 mb-0 text-grey-900 font-xssss mt-0 me-4">
                                                Delete
                                                <span className="d-block font-xsssss fw-500 mt-1 lh-3 text-grey-500">Save to your saved items</span>
                                            </h4>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        ))}

                        <MediaCarousel
                            images={images}
                            currentIndex={selectedImageIndex}
                            dialogVisible={showModal}
                            onClose={() => {
                                setSelectedImageIndex(-1);
                                setShowModal(false)
                            }}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}


export default MediaTab;
```

And here my MediaCarousel:

```
import {Dialog} from 'primereact/dialog';
import {Carousel} from 'primereact/carousel';
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./index.css";

function MediaCarousel({images, currentIndex, onClose, dialogVisible}) {

    const displayImage = (image) => {
        return (
            <div className="border-1 surface-border border-round m-2 py-5 px-3">
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <img src={`${image.imageUrl}`} alt={`${image.id}`}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <Dialog
            visible={dialogVisible}
            position={"left"}
            modalStyle={{width: '70%'}}
            onHide={onClose}
            draggable={false}
        >
            <Carousel
                value={images}
                numVisible={1}
                numScroll={1}
                orientation="vertical"
                circular={true}
                verticalViewPortHeight="360px"
                itemTemplate={displayImage}
                page={currentIndex}
            />
        </Dialog>
    )

}

export default MediaCarousel;
```

Thank in advance

I checked all state values when I click on an image. Even try to group the MediaCarousel inside MediaTab with a condition to show like below but still doesn't work

```
 {showModal &&
                            <MediaCarousel
                                images={images}
                                currentIndex={selectedImageIndex}
                                dialogVisible={showModal}
                                onClose={() => {
                                    setSelectedImageIndex(-1);
                                    setShowModal(false)
                                }}
                            />
                        }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.